# Why does this MVC4 Web API route not work compared to an ASP.NET website project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In a MVC4 Web API project has the "itemtypelist" route below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
  name: "itemtypelist",
  url: "{controller}/list/{itemtype}/{searchtext}",
  defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "list", itemtype = (string)null, searchtext = (string)null }
  );

}
```

which is intended to map to the following controller action

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IEnumerable<Repository.ViewModel.Brand> List(string itemType, string searchText)
```

and URL

```
/api/brand/list/mytype/mysearchtext
```

However, the URL returns a 404 message. This route and controller action work in a website project, but not in the Web API project. What is different in the MVC4 Web API project that would cause the action not to be found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is different in the MVC4 Web API project that would cause the action not to be found?

Everything is different. Absolutely everything. Starting from the way you configure your API routes, going through the entire model binding, up until the base controllers. So basically you forget everything you know about ASP.NET MVC if you want to develop a Web API. Microsoft have duplicated every single thing. It's a new design, new assemblies, new namespaces, new API. Nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

So if you want to configure Web API routes you need to use the `MapHttpRoute` extension method and not the `MapRoute` which is only for standard MVC controllers. Do not confuse the base `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` (which you are accustomed in using in your MVC applications) with the `System.Web.Http.ApiController` (which is the base class for your API controllers). Those are two completely different beasts.

So here's how to configure a route for an ApiController:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultAPI",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also notice that in a RESTful API you do not specify the action name in the route. It is assumed from the HTTP verb used to consume it. Here's a [`good article`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) I recommend you reading about RESTful routing in the Web API.

By the way if you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project using either the internet or the empty template you will notice that Visual Studio will create 2 files for you:

1. `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` - where you put all your standard MVC routes
2. `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` - where you put all your Web API configuration (including routes, custom formatters, ...)

You will also notice that they are using 2 completely different approaches. Do not forget that the Web API could be self hosted, for example in a Console Application. That's why Microsoft decided to implement everything from scratch. They didn't want any coupling with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Yea, I was editing the wrong config file... Thanks for pointing that out. Re: the REST api, in some cases the verb approach is not robust enough and one can specify a more complex route. I have found this needed when the calling entity needs to pass a complex set of information, e.g., filter criteria. Also, for security reasons everything has to be a POST, no GETs.

Comment: No, believe me, the REST approach is extremely robust. Much more robust than anything else. If you end up with many route definitions violating the RESTful conventions it simply means that your design is wrong and you have incorrectly defined your resources and the operations with those resources.

Comment: How would you deal w/ something like the set of filter criteria that kayak.com uses for a flight search? For example, if you need to pass 6-10 criteria to retrieve a list of flights? Also, the # of criteria would vary, i.e., you would pass anything from 0 to max criteria.

Comment: I would very simply pass them as query string parameters to a default and RESTful route called `GET /flights`. So for example you could have `GET /flight?foo=bar` or if you want more filters `GET /flights/foo=bar&baz=bazinga`. In all cases your resource here is a **flight** => you will have an API `FlightsController` and of course an `IEnumerable<Flight> Get(FilterViewModel searchCriteria) { ... }` controller action that will respond to GET verbs for the flights resource. When designing a RESTful API all you need to think about is what are your resources and what actions you could have.